# Changes in a base color of an admin page

Tags: icons, interface, color

I am changing a support page of my company to make the employees more happy and comfortable with the support page. I came with a question. Can a redesign really change the way users feel or will big changes just make them uncomfortable with the new positions and colours?

This is what the current page looks like.

[image: Old Screen]

This is the new design I'm creating. It's a document download page.

[image: New Screen]

Comment: Hi Marcelo, it's not clear what your question is. Can you try to ask again in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask yourself what your goal is. Why do you want to change the design? More comfortable is not very clear reason, how can measure it? But you can measure productivity! How fast your customers find needed document, how many clicks they do. Talk to them about their satisfaction, to real customers, not to us :)

I want to share with you the vision maps -- these analyses show what your visitors see in the first couple seconds:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you generate such vision maps?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'll create some prototype and do the tests live with them, i'll also ask them later about how they are felling, what they think and if something went wrong in the process, by the way, how do you create this vision map ?

Comment: @UXResearch  with the help of this tool -- http://heat-map.co